# arraylist.size() java null pointer exception

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have read other answers to try to find the solution but nothing clearly explains the issue.

Why should the following code block create a null pointer exception for currArraySize?

```
    int biggestArraySize = 0;
   int currArraySize = 0;

   for(int i = 0 ; i < myMap.keySet().size(); i++){

       ArrayList<String> currList = new ArrayList<String>();

      currList =  myMap.get(i);

      currArraySize = currList.size();

       if(currArraySize > biggestArraySize){

        biggestArraySize = currArraySize;

        }

    }


    System.out.println(biggestArraySize);
```

Comment: Clearly you have a null value somewhere in your set.

Comment: `myMap.get(i)` is returning `null`, because `Integer.valueOf(i)` isn't in your map's keyset; to put it another way, your map's keys aren't the integers `0` to `myMap.keySet().size()-1`. If you want to iterate the values, use `for (ArrayList<String> currList : myMap.values())`.

Comment: Look at the answer to the duplicate question used to close this one, at the general steps used for debugging NullPointerExceptions (NPE's). You will see more of these, trust me, a **lot** more of them, and you'd best learn best practices on how to debug them now.